# How to secure data stored in iOS and Android by flutter?

Tags: android, ios, security, flutter, encryption

everyone,
I am planning to develop an app that needs to save sensitive data locally and on the cloud.
I will use flutter to develop.

The figure below shows the dataflow. 
Here are some points:

1. The data (including strings and pics and videos) are encrypted locally.
2. The server only accepts and store encrypted data.
3. The data stored in the client cannot be easy to access. If the data is accessed by others, it needs to be hard to be hacked.

Edit: I want to lower the risk of the local.

Thanks for everyone who is willing to help me!

[image]

Comment: Could you summarize the sort of threats you are trying to mitigate? For example, are you assuming that the data in transit is secure/accepted risk and purely trying to mitigate local attacks?

Comment: Hi, Steve. I want to lower the local risk. I think it will be low risk while transiting encrypted data on the internet.